# Cron job not kicking off every 30minutes

Tags: php, linux, cron

i want the following page to be accessed to update news for my site, but i noticed it is not executing every 30minutes as i would like it to.

Would appreciate if you see any issue with my line below after hitting

crontab -e

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget http://servername.us/application/api.php5?action=topnews_update=1 -q > /dev/null
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the command run OK in console?

Answer (score 2):

Try `0,30` rather than `*/30`. Some unixes do not support the `*/`, so although perhaps not likely, it's worth a shot hardcoding the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I use this configuration and it works for me,

```
0-59/15 * * * *
```

This is for running every 15 mins.
for your condition replace 15 by 30.